# Video stabilization for a timelapse video of paraglider flight?

Tags: stabilisation, time-lapse

Below you can see a sample of paragliding video recording. As pilot I'm trying to fly straight, but my harness (and camera) keep moving back and forth, left and right, every 2-3 seconds.

What is the best way to do a smooth time-lapse video out of this clip? A "plane alike" effect? I assume that I could use 1 frame of every ~5-second clip, just not necessarly uniformly distributed.

Comment: I don't see any way to do this without creating special events in your video editor.

Comment: Very time consuming and probably won't get as good results as you're hoping for